# Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit a a VM in VMWare Workstation 9.0 no Alt-Gr keys on french keyboard

Tags: keyboard, 64-bit, keyboard-layout, vmware

Using VMWare Workstation 9.0  I install a new VM with Ubuntu server 14.04 64-bit ISO.

I install just the core, I use a french keyboard and during setup I enter the detect part of my keybord.

Then When I logged in, all is well the keyboard is in french layout (azerty ...), the SHIFT keys are working (characters with accents).

The problem is that I can't access the Alt-Gr keys like | or [] etc... for a server with just a command line it's a bit annoying.

I do multiple test with :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

But still nothing !

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [AltGr key combinations do not work in Linux virtual machines that are remotely accessed by VMware Infrastructure Client running in a Windows RDP or VNC session (1022454)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022454).

This issue is caused by multiple protocol translations by third party software.

When you press AltGr in Windows, VK_CONTROL and VK_MENU virtual keys are generated. The Linux virtual machines receive an extra Control_L key event which prevents them from recognizing the AltGr key combination.

I do not apply the solution given in this article. I just connect to my server using putty (openSSH server).